# Show that the inclusion $\mathbb{RP}^2\to\mathbb{RP}^3$ induced by the inclusion $S^2\to S^3$ is not homotopic to the constant map

Tags: algebraic-topology, projective-space

I'm dealing with the following question:

Consider the inclusion $i : \mathbb{R}P^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^{3}$ induced by the inclusion of $S^{2}$ into $S^{3}$ as its equator.
Show that $i$ is not homotopic to a constant map.

It's a practice problem, but I'm stuck on how to show this. I feel as if it's a very simple step that I'm missing?

Comment: It would help if you gave a bit more context. Do you know about the fundamental groups of these spaces?

Comment: Do you know CW-complexes and cellular approximation?

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes, I do. Can you guide me towards the answer?

Comment: Hint: Consider the induced homomorphism of fundamental groups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is well-known that $\mathbb RP^n$ has a CW-structure with one cell in each dimension. In  fact, $\mathbb RP^n$ is obtained from $\mathbb RP^{n-1}$ by attaching an $n$-cell. See [CW complex structure of the projective space $\mathbb{RP}^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/194735). Thus the $k$-skeleton of $\mathbb RP^n$ is $\mathbb RP^k$. By cellular approximation we see that the inclusion $i : \mathbb RP^2 \to \mathbb RP^3$ induces an isomorphism
$$i_* : \pi_1(\mathbb RP^2) \to \pi_1(\mathbb RP^3).$$
This is just a special case of the fact the the inclusion $i : X^2 \to X$ of the $2$-skeleton $X^2$ of a CW-complex $X$ induces an isomorphism $i_* : \pi_1(X^2) \to \pi_1(X)$.

But is well-known that $\pi_1(\mathbb RP^2) \approx \mathbb Z_2$, thus $i$ cannot be null-homotopic (in that case we would have $i_* = 0$ which is not an isomorphism).